# Order DOM elements located in separate divs with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, sorting

I'm working on a jQuery code which sorts all the divs with class "order_me" in a page according to such a criterion.

These divs are arranged in container rows made by divs, i.e.:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div  class="order_me"></div>
      <div  class="order_me"></div>
      <div  class="order_me"></div>
    </div> 
    <div class="row">
       <div  class="order_me"></div>
       <div  class="order_me"></div>
       <div  class="order_me"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
       <div  class="order_me"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Once that I get the list of divs to be ordered, i.e.

```
var $lst = $('#container').find('.order_me'));
```

and then I convert the list as JS Array and I sort it like follows:

```
var array = jQuery.makeArray($lst);
array.sort(sortingFunction);
```

Since I have the list of already sorted divs: **how can I efficiently put the sorted divs in the rows?**

Of course, if you have something else in mind show me your idea.

Note that the last row could have less divs, while the others have the same number of divs.

Thanks in advance.
Regards. JV

Comment: Do you always have 3 ordered divs per row? If so then you'll want to loop through and keep a counter. Append to the appropriate row or add new rows as needed.

Comment: Well, the last row could have less divs! Obviously the number of divs to be ordered is constant and also the number of rows is kept after the sorting! Hence one can get the number of divs currently put in a row before the sorting (which will be equal after the sorting).

Comment: Are you ordering/sorting by number? words?

Comment: @Wirey Well, I have different criteria. They depend on a <select>. Some of them are easy (e.g. string comparison), others are more complicated and requires special data retrieval inside the doc. Does it matter? Couldn't I only suppose to just have the sorted list?

Comment: @SheikhHeera Suppose that the sorting is already done.

Comment: it's done by the `sortingFunction`, so no need to know the implementation as long as we know the return type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me give a shot:

```
var $rows = $('.row');
var limit = $($rows[0]).find('.order_me').length;
var $lst = $('#container').find('.order_me'));
var array = jQuery.makeArray($lst);
array.sort(sortingFunction);

var count = 0;
var rowIndex = 0;
for(var i in array){
    var div = array[i];
    $($rows[rowIndex]).append($(div));
    count++;
    if(count >= limit){
        count = 0;
        rowIndex++;
    }
}
```

basicly I captured the number of divs in the first row to use as limit
I loop through the array, append the div to the row based on rowIndex and add to the counter.
when counter reaches limit we start to append divs to the next row by increasing rowIndex, until all elements are appended to the right place.

Comment: First, let me thank you for the answer. It is very similar to mine implementation. It is effective, but do you think that it is efficient? Consider that I have to sort up-to 1000 items.  Of course, I'm interested in GUI response time: I know that sorting 1000 object is fast, but I don't know that it will affect the what shown on the browser.

Comment: I'm choosing this solution since it seems to be faster in a lot of experiments that I carried out.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
var $lst = $('#container').find('.order_me'));
var array = jQuery.makeArray($lst);
array.sort(sortingFunction);
$('#container').html(array); // add them to container
for(var i=0; i < $divs.length;i+=3){ // loop through and wrap them in divs
   $('#container div.order_me').slice(i,i+3).wrapAll('<div class="row"></div>');  
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FkkGj/

Comment: Interesting! What do you think about efficiency? Please, read my first comment to **SparK** solution. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by exchanging the values? there are no values getting exchanged